# How to find out which features in a feature vector are the most important?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I want to increase the weight of some features in a features vector of 82 elements having 6 trained classes each of around 120 images. What's the best way to do so? A code or example would be appreciated.

Comment: feature selection is depending on the classifier - which one do you plan to use? Some have built-in support for it.

Answer (score 0):

The general class is called "Principal Component Analysis".  Search that for details on your preferred channel.

One general attack is to train a model -- or analyze the space in some other way.  Once we have a model, we check the parameter influences: cross-correlation (or other variance analysis), clustering strength, primacy of factors in Naive Bayes, etc.

Very simply, and input feature that doesn't contribute enough (we define the threshold) gets deleted from the model.  Retrain with the reduced data, repeat until sufficiently clean.

Comment: May you add an example or a link to one..might not be as simple as that for a Matlab newbie.Thanks

Comment: I'm a ML generalist; haven't done much with MatLab directly.  You'd do better with a search of your own, where you could filter the hits for your own needs.  I don't know whether MatLab has a PCA package.